# Multiple rows with jcarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I'm trying to use jcarousel to build a container with multiple rows, I've tried a few things but have had no luck. Can anyone make any suggestions on how to create it?

Comment: Why don't you show us the code you have tried thus far so we have something to work from...

Comment: What is the code you have tried? I'm thinking it will require an extension or modification to jCarousel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have had to make a similar modifiaction.  We do this by extending the default options, to include a rows value, and the width of each item (we call them modules) then divide the width by the number of rows.

Code added to jCarousel function...

Add to default options:

```
moduleWidth: null,
rows:null,
```

Then set when creating jCarousel:

```
$('.columns2.rows2 .mycarousel').jcarousel( {
        scroll: 1,
        moduleWidth: 290,
        rows:2,
        itemLoadCallback: tonyTest,
        animation: 'slow'
    });
```

The find and edit the lines in:

```
$.jcarousel = function(e, o) { 

if (li.size() > 0) {
...
moduleCount = li.size();
wh = this.options.moduleWidth * Math.ceil( moduleCount / this.options.rows );
wh = wh + this.options.moduleWidth;

this.list.css(this.wh, wh + 'px');

// Only set if not explicitly passed as option
if (!o || o.size === undefined)
   this.options.size = Math.ceil( li.size() / this.options.rows );
```

Hope this helps,

Tony Dillon

Comment: could you please add where you put these lines of code, thanks

Comment: I might have done something else wrong to need this but in pos:function(i, fv) I added this

if(i >= this.options.size)
{
     i = i - this.options.size;
}
in order to get the scroll action to loop back to the right place when clicking on the bottom row

Comment: i have try this and it i working great!but there is one problem in this record are not showing in order.

Answer (score 10):

This is .js code substitutions according to @Sike and a little additional of me, the height was not set dynamically, now it is.

```
var defaults = {
        vertical: false,
        rtl: false,
        start: 1,
        offset: 1,
        size: null,
        scroll: 3,
        visible: null,
        animation: 'normal',
        easing: 'swing',
        auto: 0,
        wrap: null,
        initCallback: null,
        setupCallback: null,
        reloadCallback: null,
        itemLoadCallback: null,
        itemFirstInCallback: null,
        itemFirstOutCallback: null,
        itemLastInCallback: null,
        itemLastOutCallback: null,
        itemVisibleInCallback: null,
        itemVisibleOutCallback: null,
        animationStepCallback: null,
        buttonNextHTML: '<div></div>',
        buttonPrevHTML: '<div></div>',
        buttonNextEvent: 'click',
        buttonPrevEvent: 'click',
        buttonNextCallback: null,
        buttonPrevCallback: null,
        moduleWidth: null,
        rows: null,
        itemFallbackDimension: null
    }, windowLoaded = false;


    this.clip.addClass(this.className('jcarousel-clip')).css({
        position: 'relative',
        height: this.options.rows * this.options.moduleWidth
    });

    this.container.addClass(this.className('jcarousel-container')).css({
            position: 'relative',
            height: this.options.rows * this.options.moduleWidth
        });

    if (li.size() > 0) {
            var moduleCount = li.size();
            var wh = 0, j = this.options.offset;
            wh = this.options.moduleWidth * Math.ceil(moduleCount / this.options.rows);
            wh = wh + this.options.moduleWidth;

            li.each(function() {
                self.format(this, j++);
                //wh += self.dimension(this, di);
            });

            this.list.css(this.wh, wh + 'px');


            // Only set if not explicitly passed as option
            if (!o || o.size === undefined) {
                this.options.size = Math.ceil(li.size() / this.options.rows);
            }
        }
```

This is the call in using the static_sample.html of the code bundle in the download of jscarousel:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel( {
        scroll: 1,
        moduleWidth: 75,
        rows:2,        
        animation: 'slow'
    });
});

</script>
```

In case you need to change the content of the carousel and reload the carousel you need to do this:

```
// Destroy contents of wrapper
$('.wrapper *').remove();
// Create UL list
$('.wrapper').append('<ul id="carousellist"></ul>')
// Load your items into the carousellist
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
$('#carouselist').append('<li>Item ' + i + '</li>');
}
// Now apply carousel to list
jQuery('#carousellist').jcarousel({ // your config });
```

The carousel html definition needs to be like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul id="mycarousel0" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
     ...<li></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks to [Webcidentes](http://www.cabezabomba.com/webcidentes/?p=308)

Comment: I tried this but I can't get it to work.  Can you come up with a jsfiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: @DanHealy : Broken link

Answer (score 1):

you might want to look at [serialScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html) or [localScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) instead of jcarousel.

Answer (score 1):

I found this post on Google Groups that has a working version for multiple rows.  I have used this and it works great. http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/2c7c4a86d19cadf9

Comment: Thanks, I used that and it works well. Google groups destroys the formatting so I had to go through and delete a ton of new lines, however.

Comment: I went through the google thread. I am supposed to added some js but I am not sure how to it? I mean do I need to modify https://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/dist/jquery.jcarousel.min.js or I can add another js file after importing this one?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solutions and found changing the original jCarousel code to be troublesome - it introduced buggy behaviour for me because it didn't play nice with some of the features of jCarousel such as the continous looping etc.

I used another approach which works great and I thought others may benefit from it as well. It is the JS code I use to create the li items to support a jCarousel with multiple rows with elegant flow of items, i.e. fill horizontally, then vertically, then scrollpages:

123 | 789
456 | 0AB

It will add (value of var carouselRows) items to a single li and as such allows jCarousel to support multiple rows without modifying the original jCarousel code.

```
// Populate Album photos with support for multiple rows filling first columns, then rows, then pages
var carouselRows=3; // number of rows in the carousel
var carouselColumns=5 // number of columns per carousel page
var numItems=25; // the total number of items to display in jcarousel

for (var indexpage=0; indexpage<Math.ceil(numItems/(carouselRows*carouselColumns)); indexpage++) // for each carousel page
{
    for (var indexcolumn = 0; indexcolumn<carouselColumns; indexcolumn++) // for each column on that carousel page
    {
        // handle cases with less columns than value of carouselColumns
        if (indexcolumn<numItems-(indexpage*carouselRows*carouselColumns))
        {
            var li = document.createElement('li');

            for (var indexrow = 0; indexrow < carouselRows; indexrow++) // for each row in that column
            {
                var indexitem = (indexpage*carouselRows*carouselColumns)+(indexrow*carouselColumns)+indexcolumn;

                // handle cases where there is no item for the row below
                if (indexitem<numItems) 
                {
                    var div = document.createElement('div'), img = document.createElement('img');
                    img.src = imagesArray[indexitem]; // replace this by your images source
                    div.appendChild(img);
                    li.appendChild(div);
                }
            }
            $ul.append(li); // append to ul in the DOM
        }
    }
}
```

After this code has filled the ul with the li items jCarousel should be invoked.

Hope this helps someone.

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

If you need a quick solution for a fixed or one-off requirement that definitely doesn't involve changing core library code which may be updated from time to time, the following may suit.  To turn the following six items into two rows on the carousel:

```
<div class="item">contents</div>
<div class="item">contents</div>
<div class="item">contents</div>
<div class="item">contents</div>
<div class="item">contents</div>
<div class="item">contents</div>
```

you can use a little JS to wrap the divs into LI groups of two then initialise the carousel.  your scenario may allow you to do the grouping on the server isn't always possible.  obviously you can extend this to however many rows you need.

```
var $pArr = $('div.item');
var pArrLen = $pArr.length;
for (var i = 0;i < pArrLen;i+=2){
      $pArr.filter(':eq('+i+'),:eq('+(i+1)+')').wrapAll('<li />');
};
```