# Multiple rows with jCarousel?

Tags: javascript, html, jcarousel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple rows with jcarousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213680/multiple-rows-with-jcarousel)

I want to display 9 pictures on a single jCarousel div, with 3 rows each containing 3 pictures. How do I manage creating multiple rows with jCarousel?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 3 rows in one carousel, then its not a carousel. jCarousel doesn't support by default what you are trying to do. You can split your images into three separate lists and then make each of them carousels...