# Make a big carousel with a lot of li items

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have a big ul list with li items. I have a lot of li items (over 200). I want to put this ul in a carousel, but I'm not sure how to do it.

This is my [html on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4mAW/), and [the code](http://jsfiddle.net/S4mAW/).

Ideally, when you click on the right button, you see the next li items. I just don't know how to do it, and I hope you can provide some guidance on where to start.

Comment: By 'carousel', you mean something like this: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Examples

Comment: Instead of re-inventing the wheel, consider using an existing plugin such as [jCarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/)

Comment: Yeah. But the problem is. I want a carousel like my jsfiddle. With four rows.

Comment: How do you generate your HTML? Would it be possible to have like one container element for every 16 `li`s? I think it's going to be hard if you really want one big `<ul>` (although probably still possible)

Comment: The html are set static in the document. But i must make a script in javascript. That javascript put al the li items in four rows. But how can i make that script

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213680/multiple-rows-with-jcarousel

Comment: In the future, just include your html (truncated to a few list items) and the code within your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this [jQuery plugin](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/?#demo) a few times.
You can easily transform your li's into a carousel-item.

If you don't want to use this plugin, you can also make multiple ul's and give them an unique ID. Set the non-active ul's hidden with css (display:none).

When you click next you can use jQuery to hide the current ul`$('#ID').hide();` And show the next ul `$('#ID').hide();`.