# jquery image sroller

Tags: jquery, thumbnails, scroller

It's more than 2 hours I'm looking for a simple jquery thumbnail scroller all over the web, but not found the exact thing which I want :(

I need a simple jquery img scroller, not slide show etc, see this:

http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_thumbnail_scroller_multiple.html

it's good one, but it only let me have one row! I have no idea why but all the plugins I found were like this, they could only handle 1 row. I need to have a simple thumb scroller which could handle 3 rows of images and 4 img in each row, and with a "Next" and "Previous" button, not anything more! (with IE7+ support)

Anyone could help me with this? I would really appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need any more help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a multi-row carousel plugin here:

http://www.richardscarrott.co.uk/app/webroot/assets/javascript/jquery/carousel/demo/

You enable multiple rows like so:

```
$('#my-carousel-3').carousel({
itemsPerPage: 3,
itemsPerTransition: 3,
easing: 'linear',
noOfRows: 2
});
```

UPDATE:

I also found a similar question here: [Multiple rows with jcarousel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213680/484072) which may answer your question.

Comment: Thanks alot, saw this but not aware of the bottom demos, I appreciate your answer

Comment: You're welcome.  If this solves your problem please mark as answered.  Otherwise, please update your question and I can try and help you some more.