# Drupal and JCarousel Views - Multiple Rows

Tags: drupal, view, jcarousel, multirow

*First off, Im well aware of this topic, but sadly I cannot seem to reply with questions to the original answer provider.  Seems Stack Overflow only wants answers on these threads so I am stuck:
[Multiple rows with jcarousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213680/multiple-rows-with-jcarousel)*

Anyhow, my problem is related to Drupal and  the use of the JCarousel module for my views. Im currently getting to the end-stage of my theme development. However, Im having a few problems with this, namely in getting a jcarousel like view style but with 2 rows instead of one.  With the following jcarousel-view.tpl.php in my theme folder, I was able to somewhat get further:

```
<?php
/**
* @file jcarousel-view.tpl.php
* View template to display a list as a carousel.
*/
?>
<ul class="<?php print $jcarousel_classes; ?>">

  <?php $i=0; $rows_number=2; //you can change the number of rows ?>
  <?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
    <?php if($i%$rows_number==0) : ?>
      <li class="<?php print $classes[$id]; ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php print $row; ?>
    <?php if($i%$rows_number==($rows_number-1)) : ?>
      </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php if($i%$rows_number!=0) : ?>
      </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Here is the end result: http://static.inky.ws/image/2302/image.jpg
As you can see, it group each set of fields for each item into a common column.  So I cannot create a full border for each individual item.  (See: http://static.inky.ws/image/2303/image.jpg for an example of what Im trying to achieve code-wise)

I can get a grid view but it means changing my view's style to use "Grid", which costs me from using jcarousel.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can improve my code above? Im thinking that the unordered list markup might not be helping me any.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://mywishez.com
All those images on front you see are displayed using jcarousel. You can confirm with firebug as well. I set the hight and set the number of items more than can be held in a row!