# Searching for a gallery jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm searching for a gallery jQuery plugin in which certain number of divs are viewed and if there is more; it shows the navigation buttons to scroll to the next group of divs .. the divs appearing and disappearing could be a little slide with fadeIn/Out ... example for what i'am searching for .. :

[Animated Gif For Example (wait a until it loads)](http://im37.gulfup.com/TbeMM.gif)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: ok ^-^" ty for your explnation :)

Comment: Actually what i need is a "Latest Works" Plugin *-*
if you now already made plugins previously please tell me ^.^

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called Carousel. A quick search revealed following results:

[15 jQuery Carousel Plugins](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/tools/jquery-carousel-plugins/)

[35+ Examples of Engaging Carousel Website Design](http://www.101webdesigns.com/2013/03/35-examples-of-engaging-carousel-website-design/)

As it is already pointed out that this is open ended question, you figure out according to your requirement that which carousel plugin suits your requirement.

HTH

Comment: Thx For answering ^-^ .. the problem is that i didn't find any multiline carousel :( ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213680/multiple-rows-with-jcarousel and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-en/LHxKhtGcrfk could help you.